# Sum of maximum quantity

Tags: function, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, formula

below is the data in my Excel it include,
Line , Styles, Feeding date and Then Each style I am having the allocated machine from Each category.
I need Extract the Sum of the machines from Each category for below table.

Needed Output

[image: Out Put]

When consider about the Line, Need to get the Maximum related to date. In this Example Showing 15 Jun for 3 style , So in that need to consider maximum of Each category. Finally need to get the sum of each lines as the final result.

If date is not available need to consider the Prior date, Example If I need to check 14 June Information Need to consider Prior date information 9 June for TAL 01 , 4 June TAL 02 and 5 Jun for TAL 03, Then need to get the sum of all 3.

Data in markdown table format:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Line | Style | Feeding Date | A | B | C | D |
| **2** | TAL01 | AAA01 | 6-Jun | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| **3** | TAL01 | AAA02 | 7-Jun | 1 |  | 3 | 1 |
| **4** | TAL01 | AAA03 | 9-Jun | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| **5** | TAL01 | AAA04 | 15-Jun | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| **6** | TAL01 | AAA05 | 15-Jun | 2 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| **7** | TAL01 | AAA06 | 15-Jun | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| **8** | TAL01 | AAA07 | 18-Jun | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| **9** | TAL01 | AAA08 | 20-Jun | 1 | 2 | 5 | 4 |
| **10** | TAL01 | AAA09 | 30-Jun | 2 | 6 | 5 | 4 |
| **11** | TAL02 | AAA01 | 4-Jun | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| **12** | TAL02 | AAA02 | 12-Jun | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| **13** | TAL02 | AAA03 | 12-Jun | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| **14** | TAL02 | AAA04 | 20-Jun | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| **15** | TAL02 | AAA05 | 22-Jun | 1 | 2 | 5 | 4 |
| **16** | TAL02 | AAA06 | 25-Jun | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| **17** | TAL03 | AAA07 | 5-Jun | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| **18** | TAL03 | AAA01 | 25-Jun | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 |

I created G-Sheet for easy reference

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17PsIzf4UOKKimduDAhnWGy6-Hh1IsxC8hIcaM8BSJmw/edit?usp=sharing

Data Sheet
I Updated the Picture with desired answer for 7 Jun and 15 Jun, So I need to get the same summation for output area considering machine type, date and Other logics.

[image]

Best regard
Indika

Comment: Ultimately you're gonna implement/use this formula in Excel or GSheets?!

Comment: Hi. I have read and re-read your question abut I can't work out - what exactly is your problem? StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. Users are very keen to help you but we expect that you have researched the issue and have made your best attempts to resolve your own problem. Would you please edit your question to describe exactly  what is your problem, summarise your research and include any of your own work to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hello Tedinoz,
So sorry for all trouble, actually I explain the my question in all way which I can. If you can walk through the detail properly I explain  everything there. 
Solution expecting in Excel sheet and I shared the G-Sheet for easy reference.

Currently I got the solution from another member and now I am walking through it.

Best regard
Indika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this in the space for result from column named `A` (`K2` in your file) and drag to the right:

```
=SUM(MAXIFS(D2:D18,
            $A$2:$A$18,"TAL0"&SEQUENCE(3),
            $C$2:$C$18,MAXIFS($C$2:$C$18,
                              $A$2:$A$18,                        
                              "TAL0"&SEQUENCE(3),
                              $C$2:$C$18,"<="&$J$2)))
```

It sums the max number of `A` where column A equals `TAL01`* and the date equals the max date found where column A equals `TAL01`* and is smaller than the date value in `J2`.

* because the use of sequence in `TAL0`&sequence(3) it calculates the max of `TAL01`, `TAL02` and `TAL03` individually and sums these.

Or to spill it in one go:

```
=BYCOL(D2:G18,
LAMBDA(x,
SUM(MAXIFS(x,
           $A$2:$A$18,"TAL0"&SEQUENCE(3),
           $C$2:$C$18,MAXIFS($C$2:$C$18,

                             $A$2:$A$18,"TAL0"&SEQUENCE(3),
                             $C$2:$C$18,"<="&$J$2)))))
```

Where the LAMBDA array `x` is looping through the columns of `D2:G18` column wise (BYCOL).

Comment: HI,
When I walk through the Answer it Showing only one line detail (TAL 01), But I need to summation of all 3 Lines for this Excel . But real scenario I am having 15 Lines, so I need to get the summation of all 15 Lines (Summation of all Lines detail)

For Easy reference I updated the formula in Google Sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17PsIzf4UOKKimduDAhnWGy6-Hh1IsxC8hIcaM8BSJmw/edit?usp=sharing

Best regard
Indika

Comment: In that case try to change both the `"TAL0"&SEQUENCE(3)` to `"TAL"&TEXT(SEQUENCE(15),"00")` (not tested)

Comment: Thanks a Lot for all support, I checked it But it not worked. In the mean time I need the solution for my excel sheet and G-Sheet share as to have better comunication.

Comment: I tested `=SUM(MAXIFS(D2:D18,            $A$2:$A$18,"TAL"&TEXT(SEQUENCE(15),"00"),            $C$2:$C$18,MAXIFS($C$2:$C$18,                              $A$2:$A$18,                              "TAL"&TEXT(SEQUENCE(15),"00"),                              $C$2:$C$18,"<="&$J$2)))` and it works. You shouldn't mixup google sheets and Excel. They're different platforms.